# No valida contraseña Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp

Hola todos que tal veran tengo un login donde he seguido todos los pasos según la documentación con la única diferencia que mi login valga la redundancia es otro la layout distinto al default es decir dentro de mi estructura de proyecto tengo algo así

> \app\src\Tempalte\layout\default.ctp
>   public.ctp

bien hasta hai mis layouts ahora el componente **auth**

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
  $this->loadComponent('Auth',[
        'authorize' => ['Controller'],
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'userModel' => 'Usuarios',
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'usuario',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Usuarios',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'authError' => 'Ingrese Datos',
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Portal',
            'action' => 'dashboard'
        ],
    ]);
}
```

mi controlador

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }  else {
            $this->Flash->error('Usuario y/o clave inválido',['key' => 'auth']);
        }
    }
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('public');
}
```

mi layout public que vendria ser mi login

```
<?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?>
                        <?= $this->Form->create() ?>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <i class="input-group-addon icon-user"></i>
                                <?= $this->Form->text('usuario',['placeholder' => 'Usuario','class'=>'form-control']) ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <i class="input-group-addon icon-key"></i>
                                <?= $this->Form->password('password',['placeholder' => 'Contraseña','class'=>'form-control']) ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <?= $this->Html->link('Olvidaste tu Contraseña','/usuarios/password');?>
                            <?= $this->Form->button('Ingresar',['class'=>'btn btn-inverse btn-right'])?>
                        </div>
                        <?= $this->Form->end()?>
```

carga todo pero siempre me manda el mensaje Usuario y/o clave inválido

por cierto los campos en mi tabla usuario es

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuario` (
   `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `usuario` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

no se que mas me falte se supone que con eso debe funcionar o donde este haciendo mal ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer el problema se encuentra en la estructura de tu tabla usuario, en la columna password, la cual debe estar en varchar de 255. Por lo tanto intenta cambiarla y haber que pasa. 
En stackoverflow en ingles, publicaron un caso parecido al tuyo, con solución, además explican muy bien el porque:
[Login [ Auth->identify() ] always false on CakePHP 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545863/login-auth-identify-always-false-on-cakephp-3)

El usuario cs01 explica muy bien el caso.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta eso era hice el cambio y funciono no me había percatado sobre ese detalle nuevamente gracias!!!